# How to get the total number of shares for a facebook post using python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the total number of shares for a Facebook post using Python

I have tried changing the connection name but it shows, such a connection does not exist.

```py
    post_1_activity_insights = graph.get_connections(id=post_1['id'],connection_name='page_post',metric='shares',date_preset='yesterday',period='lifetime',show_description_from_api_doc=True)
    print(post_1_activity_insights)
```

Could you please let me know the exact connection name to be used here?